# How do I publish my Azure DevOps release?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I see that my releases are accessible even when I'm logged out, but I don't see the binaries that were generated available for download:

https://dev.azure.com/edkolis/FrEee/_releaseProgress?_a=release-pipeline-progress&releaseId=5

How can I get a link to the binaries so people can download them without clicking through a zillion screens in Azure DevOps? I can't even find the binaries myself; there's no chance of a random user being able to find them!

Answer (score 0):

You can download your artifacts from the Build history UI. Select the successful build from your build history, 
1,
You can find download your artifacts **from the right top corner**, or from the **Summary** page, Check below screenshot.

[image]

2,
Right click on the artifacts from **Summary** page, You can copy the download link addresss.

[image]

3,
You can also get your artifacts by calling restful API, for below example. You can get the downloadUrl from the response:

```
curl -u $AZURE_USERNAME:$AZURE_TOKEN "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/$SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT/_apis/build/builds/$BUILD_BUILDID/artifacts?artifactName=drop&api-version=4.1")
```